# Selected color is not setting to back bean in primefaces colorpicker

Tags: java, primefaces

Am using p:colorpicker for selecting color in popup mode. But what happens is when I update the selected color value is shown as null and not getting updated.Seeking for help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On action use process attribute provide id of colorPicker. It works. Or on change event process itself and update too. If it doesn't work provide code snippet.